# External IP becomes unreachable sporadically

Tags: firewall, nat, pfsense

I have a very strange problem -

We have a lease line with 50 odd external IP addresses on it. We do a 1:1 assignment and Outgoing IP assignment to interfaces on a pfsense proxy server.

For each interface there is a Cisco RV215W on the interface's VLAN.

One of these VLAN's require ports 443, 25, 80 and a VPN port to be opened and forwarded to a device on the LAN. From the WAN in firewall rules on pfsense, we have allowed all traffic to the interface's NET address. On the Cisco we then do the port forwarding. We also access the Cisco's remotely using https://remoteip:8443.

This setup works, at least for 24 hours or so until we can no longer telnet in on any port or get remote access to the Cisco. We can however Ping the external IP address assigned to the interface.

This only happens on this one interface. When the connection drops, we can still access other Cisco's externally. A reboot of the Cisco resolves the issue for another period of time until it happens again.

Any ideas what is going on here?

EDIT -

When this first started happening, it was only the problematic VLAN's router that was managed externally on port 8443, the rest were managed on 443 remotely. When the IP went down first time, all ports were unreachable apart from 443. This suggests another router had accidentally been assigned the same IP, but this is not the case. We have now changed all routers to be managed externally to 8443.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That still sounds a lot like an IP conflict internally, given a reboot of the Cisco resolves it temporarily. Check the ARP cache on pfSense next time it happens for the affected device, see if the MAC matches what you're expecting.